# abrupt changes in values of x and y

Tags: java, geometry

In the below piece of code, theta x and y are varying smoothly for small values of theta, but for large values of theta, abrupt changes occur, x and y dont change for quite some time, then change abruptly.

```
float tantheta=height/base;

double theta=-Math.atan(tantheta);      

x=(int) (53*Math.cos(theta)+x0);
y=(int) (53*Math.sin(theta)+y0);
```

Comment: What are the types of `height` and `base`?

Comment: When evaluating complicated mathematical expressions, larger numbers generally take more time to process. *x and y don't change for quite some time...* How much time are you looking at?

Comment: height and base are int data types, the time means that they change by small increments when theta is small, but as theta becomes larger, the increments become larger.

Comment: Could you show us the abrupt changes? Add some `System.out`s and post your results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David, Your idea is right, but I needeed the theta for I want to use it to simulate projectile motion, my problem is solved as I change height and base to double on attila's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have some lengths (height and base) and convert to an angle (theta), then back to a length, you are doing unnecessary work.

Pretend for a minute that base and height are positive just to draw a picture. The math works for any base and height.

Imagine a triangle with one vertex at the origin and another vertex at (base, height). The sides of the triangle are (0,0) to (base,height) and (0,0) to (base, 0) and (base,0) to (base,height). Let hypot = sqrt(base*base + height*height). Note that theta is the angle of the triangle at the origin. This means that cos(theta) = base/hypot and sin(theta) = height/hypot.

So, for example, your formula for x becomes x = x0 + 53 * base / hypot;

These formulas for cos and sin will work for any base and height, positive or negative.

You are almost certainly seeing jumping because of floating point errors when base or height is close to zero. These will go away if you skip calculating theta.